# Umbraco & Archetype: Get only the first fieldset from property

Tags: c#, asp.net, umbraco, umbraco7

I'm using Archetype property editor and trying to grab only the first fieldset using foreach:

```
foreach (var fieldset in Umbraco.Content(5369).GetPropertyValue<Archetype.Models.ArchetypeModel>("myProperty"))
 {
   var icon = Umbraco.TypedMedia(fieldset .GetValue("icon"));
   <img src="@icon.Url" />
   <span>@fieldset.GetValue("iconTitle")</span>
 }
```

Fieldset is of type {Archetype.Models.ArchetypeFieldsetModel}.
How can I get only the first fieldset ?

**EDIT** Tried:

```
var fieldset = Umbraco.Content(5369).GetPropertyValue<Archetype.Models.ArchetypeModel>("hotelFacilitesIcons").Fieldsets;
```

This gives me `Archetype.Models.ArchetypeModel.Fieldsets' is inaccessible due to its protection level`

Tried:

```
var fieldset = Umbraco.Content(5369).GetPropertyValue<Archetype.Models.ArchetypeModel>("myPropertyAlias");
var facility = fieldset.GetPropertyValue<List<Archetype.Models.ArchetypeFieldsetModel>>("myFieldSetAlias");
```

This gives me: `'Archetype.Models.ArchetypeModel' does not contain a definition for 'GetPropertyValue'` from second line

Comment: I don't have much experience yet of the Archetype package but my first piece of friendly advice would be not to hard-wire content node id's into your code unless you were only doing that for demonstration purposes. It's not portable or future proof and is a real pain if/when the node id needs to change. There are some very flexible methods of traversing the content tree to get the node you need or at least pass it in as a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

I'll have a stab at perhaps trying to point you in the right direction. Looking at a previous project I have been involved in there is a `Archetype.Models.ArchetypeFieldsetModel` type so perhaps your content property might return a collection of `Archetype.Models.ArchetypeFieldsetModel` instead of `Archetype.Models.ArchetypeModel`?

E.g.

```
var fieldset = Umbraco.Content(5369).GetPropertyValue<List<Archetype.Models.ArchetypeFieldsetModel>>("myProperty").FirstOrDefault();
var icon = Umbraco.TypedMedia(fieldset .GetValue("icon"));

<img src="@icon.Url" />
<span>@fieldset.GetValue("iconTitle")</span>
```

Comment: yes, you are right: `your content property might return a collection of Archetype.Models.ArchetypeFieldsetModel` (this is the `fieldset` variable) by traversing the property (which is a `Archetype.Models.ArchetypeModel` ), like in my example.

Comment: the property (ArchetypeModel) contains multiple fiedlsets (ArchetypeFieldsetModel) each having 2 fields, and I need to grab only the first fieldset with its values

Comment: my example works, it just returns all the fieldsets.

Comment: Then can you not call ```.FirstOrDefault()``` on your collection to get the first one, you don't need the ```foreach```? I've amended my answer to provide an example.

Comment: this gives me: `Archetype.Models.ArchetypeModel does not contain a definition for GetPropertyValue` , please see my update in post

Answer (score 1):

I have sort of done the same thing in my case wanted to make sure the first archetype has got its first value set before getting all the others so how i got around it was by creating a var with the archetypes (which will give you a list fo one or more) then get the first one and check its value like below;

```
var contentSectionArchtype = Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<ArchetypeModel>("myArchetypeAlias");
        var firstSection = contentSectionArchtype.First();
```

then the first section was always the first archetype which i would then check its first value before looping through all of them, hope that helps.